# How can I update my React project's Webpack configuration to be more modern and faster?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, webpack, webpack-5

I'm asking for advice from the community. A couple of years ago, I made myself a React project configuration on Webpack. Since then, I have occasionally added new features to it, but not rebuilt it for the foundation.
During this time, it seems to me that there have been many changes and my configuration may have become outdated.
So. Maybe someone can suggest what can be changed / added to the configuration to make it more modern, better and maybe even faster? Many thanks to everyone who helps!

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { DefinePlugin, ProvidePlugin } = require('webpack');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const openBrowser = require('react-dev-utils/openBrowser');

const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const IS_DEV = NODE_ENV === 'development';

const COMMON_PLUGINS = [
  new ProvidePlugin({
    React: 'react',
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/index.html'),
  }),
  new DefinePlugin({
    'process.env.CLIENT_ID': `'${process.env.CLIENT_ID}'`,
  }),
];

const CSS_COMMON_OPTIONS = [
  {
    loader: 'postcss-loader',
    options: {
      postcssOptions: {
        plugins: ['postcss-preset-env'],
      },
    },
  },
  {
    loader: 'sass-loader',
    options: {
      additionalData: `
              @import "src/assets/styles/_mixins.scss";
              `,
    },
  },
];

const setupDevtool = () => {
  return IS_DEV ? 'source-map' : false;
};

const generateFileName = (type, extension) => {
  return IS_DEV ? `[${type}].${extension}` : `[${type}].[fullhash].${extension}`;
};

const clientConfig = {
  mode: NODE_ENV ? NODE_ENV : 'development',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.json', '.css', '.scss'],
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
  },
  entry: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.tsx')],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: `js/${generateFileName('name', 'js')}`,
    chunkFilename: IS_DEV ? '[name].bundle.js' : '[name].[hash:base64:5].chunk.js',
    assetModuleFilename: 'static/img/[name].[hash].[ext]',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.[tj]sx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-typescript'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.module\.s[ac]ss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: IS_DEV ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: {
                mode: 'local',
                exportLocalsConvention: 'camelCase',
                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
              },
            },
          },
          ...CSS_COMMON_OPTIONS,
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
        exclude: /\.module.(s[ac]ss)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: IS_DEV ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
          },
          ...CSS_COMMON_OPTIONS,
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        type: 'asset',
        resourceQuery: /url/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
        resourceQuery: { not: [/url/] },
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|webp)$/,
        type: 'asset',
      },
    ],
  },
  devtool: setupDevtool(),
  plugins: IS_DEV // Dev without MiniCss for ho treload
    ? [...COMMON_PLUGINS]
    : [
        ...COMMON_PLUGINS,
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
          filename: `styles/${generateFileName('name', 'css')}`,
          chunkFilename: `styles/${generateFileName('id', 'css')}`,
        }),
      ],
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      minSize: 20000,
      minRemainingSize: 0,
      minChunks: 1,
      maxAsyncRequests: 30,
      maxInitialRequests: 30,
      enforceSizeThreshold: 50000,
      cacheGroups: {
        defaultVendors: {
          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
          priority: -10,
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
        },
        default: {
          minChunks: 2,
          priority: -20,
          reuseExistingChunk: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    open: false,
    hot: IS_DEV,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    onListening: (devServer) => {
      if (!devServer) throw new Error('webpack-dev-server is not defined');

      const currentAddress = devServer.server.address();

      openBrowser(`http://${currentAddress.address}:${currentAddress.port}`);
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can potentially add:

```
cacheDirectory: true,
```

to babel-loader:

> cacheDirectory: Default false. When set, the given directory will be
> used to cache the results of the loader. Future webpack builds will
> attempt to read from the cache to avoid needing to run the potentially
> expensive Babel recompilation process on each run. If the value is set
> to true in options ({cacheDirectory: true}), the loader will use the
> default cache directory in node_modules/.cache/babel-loader or
> fallback to the default OS temporary file directory if no node_modules
> folder could be found in any root directory.

[Source](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader)